# AIX-Need to add lines after identifying the Pattern in the file using Non-GNU - Sed

Tags: text-processing

I have the following file:

```
export TMOUT

PS1="$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} "
PS1="${FGOLD}$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} ${NORMAL}"  
PS1=abd  
PS1="$(hostname):$LOGNAME:\$PWD $PROMPT "  
export PS1 LANG
```

I need to add the line below under the line matching `export TMOUT`:

```
FGOLD=`echo "\033[1;32m"`
```

So, the final output should look like this:

```
export TMOUT  
FGOLD=`echo "\033[1;32m"`    

PS1="$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} "
PS1="${FGOLD}$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} ${NORMAL}"  
PS1=abd  
PS1="$(hostname):$LOGNAME:\$PWD $PROMPT "  
export PS1 LANG
```

The command below is not working:

```
sed 's/.*export.*\TMOUT./&\FGOLD=`echo "\033[1;32m"`/' pro
```

outputs:

```
export TMOUT  

PS1="$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} "
PS1="${FGOLD}$(hostname):${LOGNAME}:\${PWD} ${PROMPT} ${NORMAL}"
PS1=abd
PS1="$(hostname):$LOGNAME:\$PWD $PROMPT "
export PS1 LANG
```

Comment: Can you edit this and start out with a question or explanation on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Right now it just looks like a code dump and I'm really not feeling like reading into it. Start out with at least a few sentences explaining what you're doing in a conversational way like "I'm trying to X and Y and I tried Z but have this problem P... " etc. THEN put your code dump so that we can have context.

Comment: -i is Gnu, not available in options !  @don_crissti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are escaping the `T` of `TMOUT`:

```
sed 's/.*export.*\TMOUT./&\FGOLD=`echo "\033[1;32m"`/' pro
                 ^
                 |-----??
```

That shouldn't make much difference but it's pointless. Then, you are also matching a character *after* `TMOUT` but your file has none (`sed` won't match the final newline). Try this instead:

```
sed 's/export TMOUT./&\nFGOLD=`echo "\\033[1;32m"`/' file
```

I don't have a non-GNU `sed` to test this on and I'm not sure if the `\n` will work in the replacement. If that doesn't work, try adding a `\` and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the newline:

```
sed 's/export TMOUT/&\    ## hit enter and continue writing on a new line
FGOLD=`echo "\\033[1;32m"`/' file
```

So, other options are:

```
perl -pe 's/export TMOUT/$&\nFGOLD=\`echo "\\033[1;32m"\`/' file
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '{
        if(/export TMOUT/){a=1}
        {
            print;
            if(a==1){
                print "FGOLD=`echo \"\\033[1;32m\"`";
                a=0
        }}}' file
```

Comment: @Sivas using which command? Did you try the non-sed ones?

Comment: still the same output.. using the Sed... perl works good @terdon   any suggestion for the  sed ?

Comment: @Sivas see updated answer. Or, just use one of the other options I gave.

Answer (score 1):

With any sed:

```
sed '/export TMOUT/ a\
FGOLD=`echo "\\033[1;32m"`' file
```

or place the string in a variable

```
myvar='FGOLD=`echo "\\033[1;32m"`'
sed '/export TMOUT/ a\
'"$myvar"'' file
```

Comment: @Sivas  Ya, you could use ansi-c quoting. It looks ugly;) `sed $'/export TMOUT/ a \\\n '"$myvar"'' file`

Comment: sorry @fd0  "sed: 0602-404 Function /export TMOUT/ a \\\n "$myvar" cannot be parsed."

Comment: both answers works good ! Thanks  fd0 & Terdon